# LWJGL array problem using casted to int float

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

Anyone that knows about lwjgl 2, im trying to use a float as index of my sampler array, it says I can't use a float as index so I casted it, but if I do that it shows nothing on screen, if I put manually the index works, but even if I cast or use another int with its value equals to the "atlas" float value casted the problem occurs. I put an if statement and it works, but having that on a fragment shader seems overkill.

Here my code before:

```
#version 150

in vec2 textureCoords;
in float frame;
in float atlas;

out vec4 out_Colour;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler[2];

void main(void){

    float x,y;
    x = (textureCoords.x /(256 / (16))) + (frame / (256 / (16)));
    y = (textureCoords.y /(256 / (16))) + (frame / (256 / ((16) * (256 / (16)))));
    
    vec4 textureColour;
    
    textureColour = texture(textureSampler[int(atlas)], vec2(x,y));
    
    if(textureColour.a < 0.5){
        discard;
    }
    
    out_Colour = textureColour;

}
```

That one just bugs out, so I wrote:

```
if(atlas == 0){
    textureColour = texture(textureSampler[0], vec2(x,y));
}
```

and it works as intended, can anyone explain to me why this happens?, I don't want to use samplerarray2d since I don't know how to do it, and I'm using LWJGL 2, and neither I want to do such overkill of having if statements on a fragment shader.

the Makogan(thanks for pointing that) said that maybe the name atlas was the problem, so i changed the code to

```
#version 150

in vec2 textureCoords;
in float frame;
in float textureSlot;

out vec4 out_Colour;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler[2];

void main(void){

    float x,y;
    x = (textureCoords.x /(256 / (16))) + (frame / (256 / (16)));
    y = (textureCoords.y /(256 / (16))) + (frame / (256 / ((16) * (256 / (16)))));
    
    vec4 textureColour;
    
    int value = 0 + int(textureSlot);
    
    textureColour = texture(textureSampler[value], vec2(x,y));
    
    if(textureColour.a < 0.5){
        discard;
    }
    
    out_Colour = textureColour;

}
```

now i tried to do int value = 0 + int(textureSlot), but if i run it all i get is a blank screen!

Sorry if my English is bad, I'm not a native English speaker!

Comment: Well a first possible cause of problems is that your variable is named `atlas` but in the example you shared you wrote: `textureSampler[int(altas)]` notice that the `l` is in the wrong spot. So it could be your shader wasn't compiling at all. At minimum the example, as is, won;t compile. Can you confirm you still get the problem if you fix the typo?

Comment: im sorry, that was an error of my when writting the question, i've tried and changed the name from atlas to textureSlot but still, if i use it as indice o do a conversion like

Comment: int value = 0 + int(textureSlot);
 
 textureColour = texture(textureSampler[value], vec2(x,y));

i just get a blank screen meaning that or the value is null or something, and if i test is the value works it works, only bugs out when used as indice of the array

Comment: Are you familiar with renderdoc? Could you run your program with it and share the value of atlas/textureSlot?

Comment: i've never used but i know it, i'll make some tests, but i've read in some threads that u can't usea dynamic values as indices in glsl, so i made a temporal solution with a switch statement and as a switch statement indice works(an obvious overkill for a fragment shader)